# getActivity() x2 in a fragment make it crashs

Tags: android, android-fragments

A simple android app with API call thanks to volley and with a MenuDrawer.

If I click one on my "Marks" part I got what I wanted.
But if I click twice my app crashs.

```
public class MarkFragment extends Fragment implements Observer {

    private Marks allMarks;
    private View initView;
    private ListView marksList;
    private View mProgressView;

    public MarkFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        initView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mark, container, false);
//        mProgressView = initView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        TaskManager.get().register(ETarget.MARKS_FRAGMENT.getId(), this);

        VolleyRequest.get().doRequest(ETarget.MARKS_FRAGMENT.getId(), RequestFactory.marksRequestGET(UserContext.myToken));
        Log.d("Gilou", "VolleyRequest");
//        showProgress(true);

        return initView;
    }

//    @Override
//    public void onResume() {
//        Log.d("Gilou", "onStart");
//        VolleyRequest.get().doRequest(ETarget.MARKS_FRAGMENT.getId(), RequestFactory.marksRequestGET(UserContext.myToken));
//    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {

        if (data instanceof VolleyError) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "[VolleyRequest] Error: " + data);
        } else if (data instanceof Marks) {
            allMarks = ((Marks) data);
            ArrayAdapter<Mark> adapter = new MarkArrayAdapter();;
            Log.d("Gilou", adapter.toString());

            marksList = (ListView) initView.findViewById(R.id.marks_list);
            marksList.setAdapter(adapter);
//            showProgress(false);
        }
    }

    private class MarkArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Mark> {

        public MarkArrayAdapter() {
            super(getActivity(), R.layout.mark_item, allMarks.getNotes());
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;

            if (v == null) {
                v = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.mark_item, parent, false);

                ArrayList<Mark> all = allMarks.getNotes();

                if (all != null) {

                    Mark i = all.get(position);

                    FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.note_container);
                    TextView note = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.project_note);
                    TextView corrector = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.project_corrector);
                    TextView projectName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.project_name);
                    TextView moduleName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.module_name);

                    if (container != null) {
                        container.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myRed));
                    }
                    if (note != null) {
                        note.setText(i.getFinal_note().toString());
                    }
                    if (projectName != null) {
                        projectName.setText(i.getTitle());
                    }
                    if (moduleName != null) {
                        moduleName.setText(i.getTitlemodule());
                    }
                    if (corrector != null) {
                        corrector.setText(i.getCorrecteur());
                    }
                }
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
```

The error I got is :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                 Process: xyz.gfelot.epiandroid, PID: 1891
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference                                                                              at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
                                                                             at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
                                                                             at xyz.gfelot.epiandroid.fragment.MarkFragment$MarkArrayAdapter.<init>(MarkFragment.java:88)
                                                                             at xyz.gfelot.epiandroid.fragment.MarkFragment.update(MarkFragment.java:76)
     [...]
```

I don't understand the error so I don't know how to fix it.

Seems a problem in getActivity() the second times.

Comment: Where is the error pointing?

Comment: obviously `update` is called at "wrong time" ... "the good time" is between `onAttach` and `onDetach`

Comment: @Selvin : Ok I so where you think I could be good to call `update` ?

Comment: do not call at all (you should unregister observer onPause/onStop and register in onResume/onStart)

Comment: I did that on other fragment and it works. If I don't call update, how do I get the data ?

Comment: "I did that on other fragment and it works" ... well, if you play [knife game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knife_game) you can save your fingers  (sometimes)

Comment: @Selvin : You seem to be a more experienced programmer than me. Good for you. But your your wiki links to make fun of me is not really constructive (it's obvious, I fix my stuff like a monkey...), I think. At least other people try to help me. And if with this I can understand something I don't get now, that's the best ! Don't you agree ? So IYPOV what's wrong ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102376/discussion-between-ragnar-and-selvin).

Comment: as I wrote you call `update` at wrong time .... fx `Observer iface = new MarkFragment(); iface.update(someVal, someOtherVal);` this will cause `getActivity()` return null ...

Comment: I agree with this. It's seems I need understand more about life cycle in android. What do you advice me to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive response when activity is finished and you must check if fragment is attached to activity

```
@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
     if(!isAdded()) return;
     rest your code
}
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
      ==Move here VolleyRequest==
    }
```

Comment: Yep it doesn't crash anymore. I was looking this way.
Just now my ListView doesn't appear because i'm not going in the `getView` method. I'm looking forward.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what happened to getActivity()

But the error message is clearly told you that you try to access a Null Pointer.

I think you can try

```
public MarkArrayAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.mark_item, allMarks.getNotes());
}
```

and

```
ArrayAdapter<Mark> adapter = new MarkArrayAdapter(getActivity());
```

If it does not work, maybe your allMarks is null.
You can try to use debug mode to detect.

Comment: Yes, i think the same thing, if your allMarks is null you can try to send it through the constructor to

Comment: it doesn't makes sens at all ... there is no differences between `class Outer { create() { new Inner() } int m1() {} class Inner { Inner()  { int i = m1(); }}}`  and `class Outer { create() { new Inner(m1()) }  int m1()  {} class Inner { Inner(int m1)  { int i = m1 }}}`

Comment: Thank guys. But mark cannot be null because when I click twice on the same part so I got the same ID for my request.